# innerHTML works in FF but not in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
var row = document.getElementById('my_id');
var newRow = row.parentNode.insertRow();
newRow.Id = myCounter;

var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(0);
newCell2.innerHTML = 'some text';
```

I'm trying to create a new row and a new cell in that row.  The above code works in FF but not in IE.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  IE expects document.CreateElement("td")  (and also for tr).  I added that and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newRow = row.parentNode.insertRow();
```

[Should be](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-93995626) `insertRow(-1)` if you mean to append to the end of the parent.

Also be careful: the `parentNode` of a `row` will be a `<tbody>`, even if you didn't include a `<tbody>` tag. This is because in HTML, `<tbody>` is considered an optional start tag, and implied if omitted before a `<tr>`. If you were expecting the `parentNode` to be the `<table>` you may be confused.

(XHTML parses tables more sensibly.)

Having said that, your code works for me in IE (given suitable markup and a valid `myCounter`). Post a failing test case?